# Before submit at least one checkbox is required

Tags: php, magento, checkbox

I have shown multiple checkboxes. When I submit I need at least one checkbox is required.

I tried this:

```
$fieldset->addField('checkboxes', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('listings')->__('Select Categories'),
            'name'      => 'cat_ids[]',
            'values'    => $categorieslist,
            'onclick'   => "",
            'onchange'  => "",
            'value'  => $cat_ids,
            'disabled' => true,
            'class' => 'category_match_to_listing',
            'required' => true,
        ));
```

even class name also not displayed in html

```
<input type="checkbox" value="14" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id">
```

If I use one value `'values'    => 'single',` required field working fine, then the html is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="category_match_to_listing required-entry" name="cat_ids[]" id="checkboxes_id">
```

When I get dynamic it doesn't work. Please suggest any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use validate-one-required instead of required entry

Comment: I tried that Even though I didn't get class attribute in O/P.,